# Use jQuery functions as event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

I wanna know if is possible append callbacks to jQuery for dom operations:

- append
- prepend
- addClass
- toggleClass
- removeClass
- val
- text
- css
- attr
- html
- hide
- etc

Something that works like new events.

Example:

```
$('#mydiv').bind('hide', function(){
    console.debug('someone call hide function')
});

//then in other js file, other function, anywhere.
$('#mydiv').hide();
//hide and output 'someone call hide function'
```

I looked at [.queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) and [jQuery.Callback](http://api.jquery.com/category/callbacks-object/), but it only will work if I made my own wrapper for this functions?

Maybe jQuery plugins?

This can be done without change all my js calls this plugin? Something that is not like this:

```
$('#mydiv').myPluginsHide();
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could override these functions with your own implementation, i.e. firing an event and calling the original function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything built-in that does that, but you could do it yourself by iterating over `jQuery.fn` (i.e. you would be overriding those functions as Felix Kling suggested):

```
var callbacks = {};
var excluded = ['constructor','init','jquery'];
for ( var key in $.fn ) {
    var orig = $.fn[key];
    if ( !orig instanceof Function || excluded.indexOf(key) != -1 )
        continue;
    (function(key,orig) {
        callbacks[key] = []; // This is the list of callbacks for this function
        $.fn[key] = function() {
            var ret = orig.apply(this,arguments); // Applies the function normally
            var elements = this, args = arguments;
            callbacks[key].forEach(function(f) { f(elements, args); }); // Calls each callback
            return ret;
        };
    })(key,orig);
}
```

Then you'd just have to add/remove callbacks to the corresponding entry in the `callbacks` object.

**Update:** don't know what I'm missing here, but can't make the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/cvNCp/1/) work. (*Edit:* ah, the classic mistake of forgetting to wrap your variables in a closure... it should work now. Also added an `excluded` list, for functions that must **not** be overriden).

Comment: You are making the common mistake of creating a closure inside a loop. For each function you created, `orig` will reference the last value that was assigned in the loop.

Comment: @FelixKling lol just realized the mistake, and was updating the code (the original code used `$.each` instead of a loop). Should work fine now! :)

Comment: Thanks, this solve my problem. I have preference for 'jquery solution' like Deferred suggested by @jcreamer898 but I don't know how to get Deffered except when I call method.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to look into jQuery.Deferred... I think it's something like this...

```
$(function(){
    $.when($('#one').hide('slow'))
        .then(function () { 
            $('#two').hide('slow') 
        })
        .then(function () { 
            $('#three').hide('slow')
        });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: `$.when` works with, say, `$.ajax`, because that function returns a `Deferred` (the `then` code would run when the ajax requests completes, not when it starts). But most jQuery functions execute immediatly, and does not return deferreds, so this solution would not work in this case.

Comment: Ah, I understand it now, the return value of `hide` is **both** a jQuery object (so you can chain invocations on it) and a Deferred (so if you use it like that, the Promise will run when the transition effect completes). Didn't know about that, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Worked to me. But how can I get Deferred to watch when other script call .hide()